# Save file to internal directory in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I downloaded the **SQLite database** from **Firebase**. It saves into device storage (*Android/data/package name/files/Download*). I want to save the database to the internal directory. (like assets folder to use it). I want no person can access to this file after decompiling app. It worked with error, what's the problem?

```
private void downloadFileFirebase(){

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("test.sqlite");
    storageReference.getBytes(1024*1024).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            final String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + DB_PATH ;
            try {
                writeToFile(bytes , path);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAILD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And:

```
private void writeToFile(byte[] bytes, String filename) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.close();
}
```

The error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/data/user/0/ir.seljad.sqlitechipher/databases (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `data/files` directory is the internal storage dir.

`assets` and `raw` directories are a build-time resources directories and does not exists on phone. this means you can not download files into them in runtime.

Also `files` dir is not accessible for `release` apps unless device is rooted and you can always use some sort of encrypted db.

Answer (score 0):

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will return the external storage path. not internal, you should use Context.getDatabasePath(String name) instead to retrieve the internal database path

Comment: thank you, sir. can you show me an example code? how to save in internal and use it?